# pg_dump and load table with UUID column PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uuid

With a postgresql v9.5 database, I want to move a table using a sql dump [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html):

```
pg_dump --host=localhost --username=postgres --port=5432 --dbname=my_db -t ,my_table > /D:\my_table.sql
```

The table has a [UUID identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) column:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
  uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  created timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  content text,
)
```

**load .sql**

This works for tables without a UUID column:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin
psql --dbname=my_db --host=localhost --username=postgres -w --port=5432 -f D:\my_table.sql
```

But for the specific table with a UUID column, I get the following error at the position of the first UUID:

> psql:D:\my_table.sql:1327: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c9ccacd8"
>
> LINE 1: c9ccacd8-7e37-40a2-8eca-e589dbe42a59 2016-06-04 09:48:00.676...

**sql file**

Here are the referred lines in the my_table.sql file:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table OWNER TO postgres;

COPY my_table (uuid, created, content) FROM stdin;
c9ccacd8-7e37-40a2-8eca-e589dbe42a59    2016-06-04 09:48:00.676592+00   \N
40ce5512-f566-495f-b709-0b2ec45e09c6    2016-06-04 09:48:57.148606+00   \N
\.
```

Comment: Can you show the offending line in the dump file?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: if table is not big, use `--inserts` to avoid `COPY` problem?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `--inserts` flag to avoid `COPY` problem

```
pg_dump --inserts --host=localhost --username=postgres --port=5432 --dbname=my_db -t ,my_table > /D:\my_table.sql
```

© to [Vao Tsun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5315974/vao-tsun)